# SQL Server 2008 XML Query

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I need some more help with another XML query.  Below is an example of a record of my XML column:

```
<Fields>
  <MappedFields>
    <Field name="FormNumber" value="21" />
    <Field name="ProcedureCode" value="T2023" />
    <Field name="CurrentDate" value="4/23/2012" />
  </MappedFields>
</Fields>
```

The field elements may appear in any order, so it can appear like this as well:

```
<Fields>
  <MappedFields>
    <Field name="ProcedureCode" value="G5532" />
    <Field name="FormNumber" value="12" />
    <Field name="CurrentDate" value="3/29/2011" />
  </MappedFields>
</Fields>
```

What I am looking for, is a query that will get the value of the Field with the name "FormNumber" for all the records in the table.  The query I have below works if the Field with the name of "FormNumber" is the first Field element in the XML.  What I need is a query that will find the Field element even if it is not the first element.  Can someone help me out with this?

```
SELECT
     X.Node.value(N'(Field/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FormNumber
FROM 
    dbo.MHTCM_LetterSent A
CROSS APPLY A.LetterXML.nodes(N'/Fields/MappedFields') AS X(Node)
WHERE
    X.Node.value(N'(Field/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'FormNumber'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a test in the xml path like `[@name="FormNumber"]`.

```
SELECT
     X.Node.value(N'(Field[@name="FormNumber"]/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FormNumber
FROM 
    dbo.MHTCM_LetterSent A
CROSS APPLY A.LetterXML.nodes(N'//Fields/MappedFields') AS X(Node)
```

Note the `WHERE` isn't needed now.

It might make more sense to move the test to the `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT
     X.Node.value(N'(./@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FormNumber
FROM 
    dbo.MHTCM_LetterSent A
CROSS APPLY A.LetterXML.nodes(N'//Fields/MappedFields/Field[@name="FormNumber"]') AS X(Node)
```

Edit- I made the paths absolute (//) and both examples are working for me.

Comment: Thats good info to note.  However, it still is only selecting the Field element if it is the first one.  I would like it to select it if it is in any order.

Comment: I would expect it to select the first Field element where name="FormNumber" even if it's not the first Field. See edit for take 2.